# vcpkg seems to cross between Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I am having many problems trying to build kMyMoney from source on Windows. I am following the procedure in the [kMyMoney wiki Build Environment](https://invent.kde.org/office/kmymoney/-/wikis/Build-environment). When I use the cmake command shown, the output includes file not found errors like this--

```
C:\Users\drfri\kMyMoney>cmake -B Build -S . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=c:/Users/drfri/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static -DVCPKG-MANIFEST-ROOT=c:/Users/drfri/kMyMoney
-- Running vcpkg install
Failed to load manifest from directory C:\cygdrive\c\Users\drfri\kMyMoney
no such file or directory
note: updating vcpkg by rerunning bootstrap-vcpkg may resolve this failure.
-- Running vcpkg install - failed
CMake Error at c:/Users/drfri/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:892 (message):
  vcpkg install failed.  See logs for more information:
  /cygdrive/c/Users/drfri/kMyMoney/Build/vcpkg-manifest-install.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Build/CMakeFiles/3.23.2/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/drfri/kMyMoney/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/drfri/kMyMoney/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I note the "/cygdrive/c/" is a Linux construct so--

1. Am I missing a switch somewhere?
2. Do I have the wrong version of vcpkg? vcpkg reports version 2023-04-07
3. The cmake version is 3.26.3-Windows
4. vcpkg.json is in the directory c:\Users\drfri\kMyMoney

The error logs don't say more than what is shown. vcpkg.json, vcpkg.cmake, and CMakeLists.txt do not contain references to cygdrive. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using the `kmm_test` branch recommended in the documentation?

Comment: Some of the tools seem to have been built with Cygwin. Cygwin is a way to port Linux based tools for Windows and C drive is mounted under `/cygdrive/c/` so this is fine.

Comment: Try providing all the paths in POSIX style:

`cmake -B Build -S . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/cygdrive/c/Users/drfri/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static -DVCPKG-MANIFEST-ROOT=/cygdrive/c/Users/drfri/kMyMoney`

Comment: @vvv444 - I am trying to build kmm 5.1.3. I previously did a git for that and succeeded in the download. That download is where I copied CMakeLists.txt. I'm trying to use vcpkg to get the dependencies.  I tried your POSIX style paths and got the exact same result

Comment: Is there anyone else who wants to offer something?